# Which one of "as" and "while" is correct here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

Inside the bank, the bank robbers are herding the hostages to the center of the room. **As**/**While** his men deal with the hostages, the leader goes into an office.

Hi. I can't figure out which one of "as" and "while" to use here or if both could be used. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: What do you see as the difference between **as** and **while** in this context?

Comment: I'm not sure. Are they completely interchangeable here? Or is there something that makes one of them more appropriate than the other?

Comment: I would say they were completely interchangeable in this context.